How to remove violation of duplicate primary key in the table in sql server?
I am encountering a customer error as they are unable to print due to violation of primary key as being duplicate, below its where i went and check for the db column in the table and saw this as the possible reason. What is the solution to prevent this?


Yor column has duplicate values just because this column is not a key ot this table, if you want any help start with the real error that you get

A Primary Key cannot contain duplicate values.
That's the whole point of them.
Trip is clearly not the Primary Key on this table.
It might be part of a Composite Primary Key, probably in conjunction with purpose_code, but definitely not on its own.
Printing should have nothing to do with Primary Keys.
If it does, it means that part of the process must be populating a [working?] table that has a Primary Key constraint with data that violates that constraint.  That's where you need to look.
And yes, this table does look a bit odd with lots of duplicated data that probably could be stored better but it doesn't have duplicated Primary Key values (I would guess that the Primary Key is probably TicketNumber).

W, the primary key for this table is VisitorWeighbridgeTicket not TicketNumber, how could i fix that issue with printing with that specific user with that number?

"VisitorWeighbridgeTicket" is the name of the Table!!  (Batcher is the database name, dbo the schema within that database).
Script the "CREATE TABLE" statement for this table and show us that.  Then find the SQL statement that is failing at the point the "printing" error happens and show us that as well.
